# Rails Improve Active Record querys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got this code:

```
     @coursesFound = @user.available_courses

@courses = []

for course in @coursesFound do
  @courseInGroups = course.user_groups
  for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id
    if @group.users.map { |u| u.id }.include? @user.id
      @courses << course
    end
  end
end
```

I works... But is there A way to improve it to have les for and if cascades?

Here is the available_courses function.

```
 def available_courses
Course.joins("LEFT JOIN
               memberships
             ON
               memberships.course_id = course_objects.id AND memberships.user_id = " + self.id.to_s + "
             JOIN
               clients_courses
             ON
               clients_courses.course_id = course_objects.id
               ").where("clients_courses.client_id = ? AND memberships.id IS NULL AND course_objects.active = ?", self.client_id, true)
end
```

Update with some explanations:

Yeah I have courses and a course has_and_belongs to many user groups
and a usergroup has_and_belongs to many users.

```
# contains all active courses of the current client
@coursesFound = @user.available_courses

@courses = []

for course in @coursesFound do

  # contains a array with all relations between this course. So I got an array of usergroups which should be allowed to see the course
  @courseInGroups = course.user_groups

  # Here I gonna check if the current user belongs to one of the groups which should be allowed to see the course -- if its true I add this course to the object I return to the view
  for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id
    if @group.users.map { |u| u.id }.include? @user.id
      @courses << course
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I had to improve something to don't get an error Result looks like this:

```
@coursesFound = @user.available_courses

@courses = (@coursesFound - @user.user_groups.collect(&:courses).flatten.compact)
```

But Result is empty ...

Comment: you lack db knowledge, seems everything could be done though a single query

Comment: Yeah I thought about this, but I don't find it out ... Normal SQL or Active Record? can you help me please?

Comment: whats the definition of `available_courses` ?

Comment: available_courses checks if a course is active (true / false) and if it is assigned to the actual client. I do a Join with three tables. added above.

Comment: I should understand the relationships too. a course has many groups and a group has many users?

Comment: `@courseInGroups = course.user_groups
  for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id` looks very weird to me, I have no idea what is the class of `@courseInGroups` (looks like its a UserGroup), then why you do `@group = UserGroup.find group.id`

Comment: I've added more info in question

Comment: why this? `for group in @courseInGroups do
    @group = UserGroup.find group.id` you have an object and requery the db to have it again?

Comment: it is highly possible that it is wrong. just assuming things and your chat. and proposing this solution `(@coursesFound - user.user_groups.collect(&:course).flatten.compact)`

Comment: where should I set this up? in loop or direktly atfer     `@coursesFound = @user.available_courses`

what does flatten and compact do?

Comment: I've added it in question how I tried it ... but result is empty.